# Detect the width and use a responsive image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an application that automatically set a width for a photo.
The problem is that sometimes it defines the size larger than the original image:
Ex: This "a.jpg" is 500px wide and 600px to define application when displaying.

For some limitations layout I have no way to change it.
I want to, when the size of image definied by application is larger than the original size, it uses another photo.

EX: If the application defines width 600px and image "a.jpg" is 500px, then it will use the "b.jpg" which is 700px width.

The image is a code like this:

```
<article class="tile">
            <a href="photos/1.jpg">
                <img class="item" src="../img/fotos/10medium.jpg" />
            </a>
 </article>
```

There's a way to do this? Thanks

Comment: It would probably be more efficient to use CSS media queries and detect the size of the visible screen, rather than the size that the application defines as the `width` of the element.

Answer (score 1):

Yes by using jquery you can do like this

```
var img = $('img');
$('<img>').attr('src', img.attr('src')).load(function () {
  if (img.width() > this.width) {
    img.attr('src', 'big-image.jpg');
  }
});
```

Comment: `(window).width()` will detect the size of the screen? or I'm wrong?
I edited the with some code.

Comment: Yes, `$(window).width()` will detect the size of the browser window

Comment: I don't wanna the browser width. I want compair the width set in html "width" with the original width on `img src`
something like: `if ($('img').width() > $('src to image').width())`

Comment: Code has been updated to compare image current set width with image original width

Comment: Based on my code in the answer I teste this code, but doesn't work:
Can you help me?`var img = $('#teste');
$('<img>').attr('src', img.attr('src')).load(function () {
  if (img.width() > this.width) {
    img.attr('src', 'http://localhost/flampic/img/fotos/4large.jpg');
  }
});
  }
});`

Comment: What is html structure, if same as in OP then var img = $('img.item') if not then please create a js fiddle and share the link

Answer (score 1):

Is a jQuery plugin an option? I think [Responsive Img](http://responsiveimg.com) does what you're trying to do, but it may not meet all of your project requirements.

If nothing else, you could look at the source code and get some clues to help with what you're doing. The plugin is small and well commented.